# PHP glob function

Tags: php, glob

I am trying to get some file paths with glob function but unfortunately it does not work, returns nothing. When I try same thing with scandir function, it works. Also when I try this function in another php file which their paths are same, it works again.

`$onlyImages = glob("datasets/777/*.{png,jpeg,jpg,bmp}",GLOB_BRACE);`

Folder tree

- Yaz

  - upload-files.php --> my main php file which the function does not work in
  - abc.php --> my test php file which the fuction works in
  - datasets

    - 777

      - a.png
      - b.png
      - c.png

        .

        .

        .
      - abcd.png

Thanks for your helps...

Comment: do `var_dump(getcwd());` to make sure you're working in the directory you expect. Note that the default directory is the working directory not the script directory

Comment: The `glob` function has no problem,find your main error

Comment: @apokryfos I checked for both. Working path is same, C:\xampp\htdocs\Yaz

Comment: @Miladpegah I could see no problem, there are some other codes after glob function and they works.

Comment: Thank you so much both, I solved the problem, glob function returns path but scandir returns name of file.